# converting threeparttable tabular to threeparttablex and longtable

Tags: longtable, threeparttable, threeparttablex

I am trying to convert an existing `threeparttable` to a `threeparttablex` table with `longtable` so I can break the table over multiple pages, but I'm having some trouble. Specifically, I'm getting an error about a misplaced \noalign related to `\toprule`. Any ideas where I am going wrong?

Original:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{threeparttablex}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[H]
\centerline{\begin{threeparttable}
  \caption{My caption}
  \label{mytbl}
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{lrrrrr}
  \toprule
      & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Grp 1} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Grp 2} &  \\
      & \multicolumn{2}{c}{(\textit{n}=500)} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{(\textit{n}=500)} &  \\
      \cmidrule(lr){2-3} \cmidrule(lr){4-5} 
      Variable & \multicolumn{1}{r}{Mean} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{SD} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{Mean} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{SD} & p-value \\
      \midrule
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
  \begin{tablenotes}
  \small
  \item My notes
  \end{tablenotes}
  \end{threeparttable}}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

New:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{threeparttablex}

\begin{document}

\begin{ThreePartTable}
\begin{longtable}{lrrrrr}
  \caption{My caption}\\
  \label{mytbl}
  \toprule
  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Grp 1} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Grp 2} &  \\
  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{(\textit{n}=500)} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{(\textit{n}=500)} &  \\
  \cmidrule(lr){2-3} \cmidrule(lr){4-5} 
  Variable & \multicolumn{1}{r}{Mean} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{SD} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{Mean} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{SD} & p-value \\
  \midrule
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  \bottomrule
  \end{longtable}
  \begin{tablenotes}
  \small
  \item Note. My table notes here
  \end{tablenotes}
  \end{ThreePartTable}

  \end{document}
```

Bonus: I'd like to add a `Continued on next page` message at the bottom of every page except the last, and a `Table X Continued` message on every page but the first.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to move your `\label{mytbl}` just after the `caption` like

```
\caption{My caption}\label{mytbl}\\  
  \toprule
```

You can put the `Continued on next page` in the same way you do with a long table:

```
  \caption{My caption}\label{mytbl}\\  
  \toprule
  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Grp 1} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Grp 2} &  \\
  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{(\textit{n}=500)} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{(\textit{n}=500)} &  \\
  \cmidrule(lr){2-3} \cmidrule(lr){4-5}
  Variable & \multicolumn{1}{r}{Mean} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{SD} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{Mean} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{SD} & p-value \\
  \midrule
  \endfirsthead

\multicolumn{6}{c}{{\bfseries \tablename\ \thetable{} -- continued from previous
page}}\\
\toprule
  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Grp 1} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Grp 2} &  \\
  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{(\textit{n}=500)} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{(\textit{n}=500)} &  \\
  \cmidrule(lr){2-3} \cmidrule(lr){4-5}
  Variable & \multicolumn{1}{r}{Mean} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{SD} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{Mean} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{SD} & p-value \\
  \midrule    
\endhead

\midrule
\multicolumn{6}{r}{{Continued on next page}} \\
\midrule
\endfoot
\bottomrule
\endlastfoot
```

Further the `tablenotes` environment must be replaced by `TableNotes` environment and it should be put before the `\begin{longtable}`. Just before `\endlastfoot` you should insert `\insertTableNotes` like

```
\insertTableNotes         %% this added
\endlastfoot
```

Full code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{threeparttablex}

\begin{document}

\begin{ThreePartTable}
  \begin{TableNotes}  %%% This should come before longtable and it is not tablenotes but TableNotes
  \small
  \item Note. My table notes here
  \end{TableNotes}
\begin{longtable}{lrrrrr}
  \caption{My caption}\label{mytbl}\\
  \toprule
  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Grp 1} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Grp 2} &  \\
  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{(\textit{n}=500)} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{(\textit{n}=500)} &  \\
  \cmidrule(lr){2-3} \cmidrule(lr){4-5}
  Variable & \multicolumn{1}{r}{Mean} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{SD} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{Mean} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{SD} & p-value \\
  \midrule
  \endfirsthead

\multicolumn{6}{c}{{\bfseries \tablename\ \thetable{} -- continued from previous
page}}\\
\toprule
  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Grp 1} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Grp 2} &  \\
  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{(\textit{n}=500)} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{(\textit{n}=500)} &  \\
  \cmidrule(lr){2-3} \cmidrule(lr){4-5}
  Variable & \multicolumn{1}{r}{Mean} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{SD} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{Mean} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{SD} & p-value \\
  \midrule    
\endhead

\midrule
\multicolumn{6}{r}{{Continued on next page}} \\
\midrule
\endfoot
\bottomrule
\insertTableNotes         %% this added
\endlastfoot

  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  %\bottomrule
  \end{longtable}
  \end{ThreePartTable}

  \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: this is excellent! Very helpful notations. Thanks for taking the time to explain it.