# Set longtable + ThreePartTable to start at the top of the next page

Tags: floats, longtable, threeparttable

Is this possible?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{threeparttablex}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[2-4]

\begin{ThreePartTable}
    \begin{TableNotes} 
        \small
        \item Note. My table notes here
    \end{TableNotes}
    \begin{longtable}{lrrrrr}
        \caption{My caption}\label{mytbl}\\

        Variable & Mean & SD & Mean & SD & p-value \\

        \endfirsthead

        \endfoot

        \insertTableNotes         
        \endlastfoot

        Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
        Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
        Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
        Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
        Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
        Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
        Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
        Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
        Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
        Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
        Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
        Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
        Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
        Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
        Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
        Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
        Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
        Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
        Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
        Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
        Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
        Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
        Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
        Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
        Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\

    \end{longtable}
\end{ThreePartTable}

\lipsum[2-16]

\end{document}
```

<sub>MWE is based on [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/196311/23538).</sub>

Comment: Longtable isn't float environment. You can move it start to the top next page with `clearpage`, however page before it will have empty space ... If the table is shorter than 1 page, than you can use standard `threeparttable` in `table` environment, which can float.

Comment: @Zarko afterpage can help....

Comment: I try with `\afterpage{\clearpage}` , however now I see, where I make error in its use! So, your answer is very valuable to me to (+1) ! AT least I should read documentation again ...

Answer (score 2):

If you are feeling brave you can defer a `longtable` until the next natural pagebreak using `\afterpage`

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{threeparttablex}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{afterpage}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[2-4]

\afterpage{\clearpage
\begin{ThreePartTable}
    \begin{TableNotes} 
        \small
        \item Note. My table notes here
    \end{TableNotes}
    \begin{longtable}{lrrrrr}
        \caption{My caption}\label{mytbl}\\

        Variable & Mean & SD & Mean & SD & p-value \\

        \endfirsthead

        \endfoot

        \insertTableNotes         
        \endlastfoot

        Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
        Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
        Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
        Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
        Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
        Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
        Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
        Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
        Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
        Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
        Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
        Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
        Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
        Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
        Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
        Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
        Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
        Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
        Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
        Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
        Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
        Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
        Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
        Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
        Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\

    \end{longtable}
\end{ThreePartTable}}

\lipsum[2-16]

\end{document}
```