# How to have Latex Table and Latex table notes have the same width?

Tags: tables

I have a standard Latex Table set as landscape that I annotate with `\begin{tablenotes}` and `\end{tablenotes}` (where I also use `\justify`). How to have the table and the table notes have the same width (i.e., the notes start at the left of the table and end at the right of the table), such that the whole table looks pretty on the portrait page?

```
\begin{landscape}
\begin{center}
\begin{table}[!ht]
\caption{}
\justifying
\begin{tablenotes}
\justify Text
\end{tablenotes} 
\par 
\begin{tabular}{lcc} 
\end{tabular} 
\end{table} 
\end{center}
\end{landscape}
```

Comment: Please provide a MWE so that we can reproduce your setting and help you out more easily.

Comment: Sounds like a duplicate of your previous question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/325385/how-to-annotate-a-latex-table-in-such-a-way-that-the-notes-are-of-the-same-width

Comment: The threeparttable does not help me align the text and the table in my landscape Table (it does in a standard table though.) Why is that?

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 3):

Try building on this MWE for `\threeparttable`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}
\begin{table}[ht]
\caption{Sample Table}
\label{tab:tlabel} 
\centering{}
\begin{threeparttable}
\begin{tabular}{lcccclcccc}
\toprule
this                   & is & a & really & wide & table & and & is & oriented & landscape \\
some numbers go here:  & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
Note: Table notes go here and should be the same width as the landscape-oriented table. \texttt{\textbackslash threeparttable} is the best!
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Tyler! I have almost exactly the same, just that I use `\usepackage{threeparttablex,booktabs}` .. why does this create a problem? Can I not simply do my threeparttables with this package?

Comment: I'm not sure about this. I'm guessing that there are some differences between `threeparttablex` and `threeparttable`, particularly if your `threeparttable` needs to be a long table (i.e. continues on another page). See [link](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/196303/converting-threeparttable-tabular-to-threeparttablex-and-longtable)

Comment: Thanks Tyler! There is still one issue though. If I add both packages (or only `threeparttable`), my portrait tables look awful -- my landscape tables look good. If I add only add `threeparttablex` only my portrait tables look good.  -- my landscape tables look bad.  Please let me know if anybody has an answer in how to fix both landscape and portrait tables at the same time :(((

Comment: Could you post a minimal example showing this problem?

Comment: @İremErten I am not sure why this is happening with `threeparttablex`. I don't have experience with that package, but if you post a minimal example like @Bernard suggested, I might be able to help you.