# Tablenotes and Captions at the bottom of Longtable

Tags: tables, captions, longtable, tablenotes

I am trying to put a note at the bottom of the following `longtable`. Unfortunately, this is the result I get.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,amsmath,bm,siunitx}

\begin{document}

{\small\setlength{\tabcolsep}{4.5pt}
    \sisetup{table-format=2.4}
    \begin{longtable}{@{}l*{8}{S}}
        \label{my-label}\\
        \toprule
        \textbf{Descriptive Statistic} &{$rtb_t$} & {$xIG_t$} & {$xHY_t$} & {$xEM_t$} & {$xConv_t$} & {$y_t$}& {$DefRate_t$} & {$spr_t$}\\
        \endfirsthead
        %
        \endhead
        %
        \toprule
        Mean & 0.1658 & 0.0378 & 0.0442 & 0.0502 & 0.0524 & 0.4233 & 0.4996 & 0.2521 \\
        Standard Deviation & 0.0459 & 0.0699 & 0.0928 & 0.0810 & 0.1250 & 0.0439 & 0.0909 & 0.0351 \\
        Variance & 0.0021 & 0.0049 & 0.0086 & 0.0066 & 0.0156 & 0.0019 & 0.0083 & 0.0012\\
        Skewness & 0.1963 & -0.9932 & -1.6310 & -4.7227 & -1.1165 & 0.1730 & 1.2201 & 2.8841\\
        Kurtosis & 2.9890 & 8.4808 & 14.6628 & 50.1189 & 8.5597 & 2.0001 & 3.7574 & 13.6014 \\
        Sharpe Ratio &{–} & 0.5404 & 0.4762 & 0.6192 & 0.4191 & {–} & {–} & {–} \\
        \bottomrule
        \caption{Sample Statistics: Bond Model}
        \begin{tablenotes}
            \textbf{Note:} Here can be the table notes
        \end{tablenotes}

\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Do you know how to overcome this and have notes plus caption well formatted?

Thanks!

Comment: If your real table is of the same length as the one you show in your question, there is no need for a `longtable`. If you indeed need a longtable, you can combine it with `threeparttablex` in order to add table notes as shown in the answer to this question: [converting threeparttable tabular to threeparttablex and longtable](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/196303/134144) Please also add the relevant packages to your code.

Comment: to have caption below long table is not smart idea. if it is really long (over two or more pages) than caption (which inform reader about table) is to late.

Comment: @Zarko I have already put all images and tables in this format, so I would like to stick to it if possible. That's why I would like to put notes at the bottom.

Comment: @madrac, notes yes, but not the captions ... however if you like to have caption on the end, put it and table notes in `\lastfoot`

Comment: @Zarko could you please provide your solution? If I apply that, I get the notes in the descriptive statistics line. I do not understand why.

Comment: @leandriis I have added the packages. I have tried to implement your solution, but I get still mess in the format. Could you provide your code for notes in a longtable? Many thanks.

Comment: @madrac, (ii)  your mwe can not be compiled (ii) your table is to wide that can be fit in text width (iii) why you not consider Mico or mine answer on your previous question? they bot fix your table in text width ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a code which fits between margins, but as the document is set in 12pt, you need to use `footnotesize` in your table, and reduce more the value of `\tabcolsep`. Note you should *not* have the caption at the end for a table that spreads over several pages.

For longtables we have to load `threeparttablex` and declare the tables notes *before* the table begins, and insert them with `\InsertTableNotes` in the `\endlastfoot` section.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{longtable, booktabs}
\usepackage[online]{threeparttablex}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{ThreePartTable}
\footnotesize\setlength{\tabcolsep}{2.6pt}
    \sisetup{table-format=-1.4}
\begin{TableNotes}
  \item[\bfseries Note: ] Here can be the table notes.
\end{TableNotes}
    \begin{longtable}{@{}l@{}*{8}{S}}
        \label{my-label}\\
        \toprule
        \textbf{Descriptive Statistic} &{$rtb_t$} & {$xIG_t$} & {$xHY_t$} & {$xEM_t$} & {$\mathit{xConv_t}$} & {$y_t$}& {$\mathit{DefRate_t}$} & {$spr_t$}\\
        \endfirsthead
        %
        \endhead
        \bottomrule \addlinespace
        \caption{Sample Statistics: Bond Model}\\
        \insertTableNotes
        \endlastfoot
        %
        \toprule
        Mean & 0.1658 & 0.0378 & 0.0442 & 0.0502 & 0.0524 & 0.4233 & 0.4996 & 0.2521 \\
        Standard Deviation & 0.0459 & 0.0699 & 0.0928 & 0.0810 & 0.1250 & 0.0439 & 0.0909 & 0.0351 \\
        Variance & 0.0021 & 0.0049 & 0.0086 & 0.0066 & 0.0156 & 0.0019 & 0.0083 & 0.0012\\
         Skewness & 0.1963 & -0.9932 & -1.6310 & -4.7227 & -1.1165 & 0.1730 & 1.2201 & 2.8841\\
        Kurtosis & 2.9890 & 8.4808 & 14.6628 & 50.1189 & 8.5597 & 2.0001 & 3.7574 & 13.6014 \\
        Sharpe Ratio &{–} & 0.5404 & 0.4762 & 0.6192 & 0.4191 & {–} & {–} & {–}\\
\end{longtable}
\end{ThreePartTable}

\end{document}
```

[image]